# Trying ZBarFragment, getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, fragment, zbar

Previously I was using ZxingFragment for my project and it worked, but the camera orientation was wrong. So now I am trying Zbar. I am using the ZbarFragment library. But the problem is I am getting Nullpointerexception and from debug values it seems that some variables of scanner class are null. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment implements ZBarFragment.ResultListener {

    private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final int ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "ZBarFragment";
    private ZBarScanner scanner;
    public ScanFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        ZBarFragment cameraFrag = new ZBarFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.sample, (Fragment)cameraFrag).commit();
        scanner = cameraFrag.getScanner();

        int[] modes = new int[] {ZBarConstants.CODE128, ZBarConstants.QRCODE};
        scanner.setModes(modes);
        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResult(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Error log:

> 09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-22 00:10:14.538:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   com.trhura.android.zbar.scanner.ZBarFragment.setModes(ZBarFragment.java:105)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   com.example.devicerentalsystem.ScanFragment.onCreateView(ScanFragment.java:41)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 09-22
>   00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-22
>   00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-22 00:10:14.538:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 09-22
>   00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-22
>   00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 09-22 00:10:14.538:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   09-22 00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 09-22
>   00:10:14.538: E/AndroidRuntime(27267):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Try put:

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

instead of

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();